# Manage different codebases using single git repository instead of submodules

Tags: git, github, chef-infra, git-submodules

After reading [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) article on submodules, it seems like they exist only to link to external git repositories from within your own. However, I am expecting submodules to simply allow you to manage multiple, separate commit histories from within one repository.

Is it possible to have non-external git repositories? I'd like to manage all of my chef cookbooks under one repository with separate commit histories for each, without needing to create a bunch of git repos

EDIT: I don't think I made my use case clear. What I meant was that I wanted to have the *list* of cookbooks for each of my servers in uniquely addressable places; not that I wanted a submodule for an individual cookbook. In this case, mu's answer addresses the problem quite effectively.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use separate git repositories?  Sound like a perfectly fine solution, and you don't explain any problem with that solution other than that you don't want to use it.

Comment: it doesn't seem conceptually sound to have a bunch of separate repositories serving essentially the same purpose. and it's also expensive to do so on github. mu's answer solves this problem quite effectively for me :)

Comment: I can understand the "expensive on Github" bit, but I fail to understand you other point.

Comment: See my edit - I think I poorly explained my problem in the question. sorry about that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do so using `orphan` branches. The `orphan` branch will start afresh from a new parent, so it won't have any commits in common with any other branch.

This way, you can have multiple branches, each corresponding to a different commit history for your respective cookbook.

So all you need to do is:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

From the [`git checkout` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

> `--orphan <new_branch>`
>
> Create a new orphan branch, named `<new_branch>`, started from `<start_point>` and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

FWIW, you can push completely unrelated branches between repositories, all you need to ensure is that the branch names space doesn't collide.

So, for example, if you have 2 existing cookbook repositories, `cookbook1` and `cookbook2`, create a new repository `cookbook`, add this repository `cookbook` as a remote in the existing repositories using `git remote add cookbook url/to/cookbook`, and now you can push your existing repo history to this repo using `cd cookbook1 && git push cookbook master:cookbook1` and `cd cookbook2 && git push cookbook master:cookbook2`

NOTE: As others have pointed out already, it makes more sense to have individual repos for each cookbook, so only use this approach if it matches your use case completely.

Comment: The working directory will contain only one of the cookbooks at any given time.  I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Hmm I think this is exactly what he is looking for, he wants to manage them all using a single repo without a shared history. He doesn't mention anything about using all the cookbooks simultaneously.

Comment: ah this actually does seem like a good solution. thanks @mu無 i'll accept this in a few minutes

Comment: @JasonMarmon: With this set-up, each branch will have its own completely separate set of files.  Only the files belonging to the current branch will be visible in the working directory.  If you switch to a different branch, the complete contents of the working directory wil be replaced by the disjoint set of files belonging to the new branch.  This set-up is useful in certain special use cases, but I fail to see how it is useful for the use case you described.

Comment: Well for my specific case, I'm setting up a few stacks on opsworks and I'd like to have the list of cookbooks separately addressable (like a repository) but under the same repository for the reasons listed above.  Branching solves this well enough - I don't know why I didn't initially consider it :p

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using separate repos for this, and then use Berkshelf to assemble them together.